# WPF and WCF Data Services Authenticate at Query level?

Tags: wpf, wcf

So, I swear i'm utterly confused by how to secure WCF Data Services. In that, is there a simplified way of checking to make sure that the client that is sending the data to the WCF Service is authenticated more so, that the client itself is the client I wrote and not some mock client?

Any URL"s that can help me decode this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an API key to "secure" my services over HTTPS and only allow access to specific IP addresses with IIS. Just override `OnStartProcessingRequest()` like so:

```
    protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs Args)
    {
        // allow the metadata to be retrieved without specifying an API key by appending $metadata on the end
        if (Args.RequestUri.Segments.Last().Replace("/", String.Empty) != "$metadata")
        {
            // check if a valid API key has been passed in (see Configuration.xml)
            if (!IsValidAPIKey(Args.OperationContext.RequestHeaders["APIKey"])) throw new DataServiceException("Invalid API key");
        }

        base.OnStartProcessingRequest(Args);
    }

    private bool IsValidAPIKey(string PassedAPIKey)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(PassedAPIKey))
        {
            Guid APIKey;

            // Configuration.APIKeys is just a simple list that reads from an XML file
            if (Guid.TryParse(PassedAPIKey, out APIKey) && Configuration.APIKeys.Exists(x => x.Key == APIKey)) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ArrayOfAPIKey xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <APIKey Key="ee5346fa-bca5-4236-ae6c-f35ae2f69e0b" ApplicationName="blah" />
</ArrayOfAPIKey>
```

My client side:

```
base.SendingRequest += (s, e) => { e.Request.Headers.Add("APIkey", "your-api-key-here");  };
```

Answer (score 0):

WCF Data Services uses the normal authN/authZ components of the vanilla WCF stack. How do you host your service (typically in IIS) and what kind of authentication scheme are you using?

Update: The Astoria/WCF Data Services team has an excellent blog post series on WCF Data Services and Authentication:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130616003151/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/tags/authentication/)

Comment: I'm looking to use a custom database approach. In that I want the client to hand down a username,password,key to WCF DataServices. I basically want to avoid keeping state and always assume the client asking for the query (CRUD) is lying and validate each time.