# OData Authentication

Tags: wcf, authentication, odata, dataservice

I have been trying to implement an OData service based upon an entity framework model where the authentication is provided by Sql Azure. I provide row/column access within the database.

I want to be able to call this from LinqPad, Excel, etc. as a secure service.

I have tried the various schemes defined in the [standard series](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/astoriateam/odata-and-authentication-part-4-server-side-hooks) but even though returning 401, neither Excel or LinqPad recall with the user name and password I've entered.

So, I thought I'd make the user name/password a query parameter (over SSL).  But it turns out that's illegal as well (OData requires a well formed URL with no query parameters).

So then I thought, why not use WebGet to embed the user name and password in the URL but I can't get that to work with the OData source format in WCF:

<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Factory="System.Data.Services.DataServiceHostFactory, System.Data.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Service="WebApplication5.OData" %>

```
public class OData : DataService< MyEntities >
{
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
    }
protected override MyEntities CreateDataSource()
{
    // create the OData source with the user name and password here
}
}
```

Has anyone actually got OData to work where the user name and password are passed into the source?

Answer (score 1):

I've not used a username and password per-say but I have authenticated by an API key which is technically the same. See my answer here: [WPF and WCF Data Services Authenticate at Query level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430208/wpf-and-wcf-data-services-authenticate-at-query-level/7447471#7447471) - I use HTTP headers to authenticate: `Args.OperationContext.RequestHeaders["APIKey"])` but you can change this to `Args.OperationContext.QueryString["APIKey"])` (not sure if `QueryString` is a property of the top of my head) to allow passing in `?APIKey=blah` in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862626/odata-default-company-and-adjusting-service-config-files-in-silverlight-app-bein) with OData for a Silverlight App with C# in that you had to create a new Uri (Url) and add in the credentials, either here or you can create a login screen to populate them:

> ServiceReference1.NAV nav = new ServiceReference1.NAV(new
>   Uri("http:...../OData/Company('company_name')/"));
>
> nav.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password",
>   "domain");